# transpose data and making fist column as header

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I´m trying to transpose the data that I obtained and make the column with Samples as a header
What I´m starting with

```
|Sample 1 | 0,4704 |
----------
|Sample 2 | 0,1501 |
----------
|Sample 3 | 0,4388 |
----------
|Sample 4 |  0,2957|
---------
```

What I'd like to have

```
sample 1    |sample 2   |sample 3   |sample 4   
----------
0,4704   |   0,1501 |    0,4388 |    0,2957 
----------
```

What I really have

```
1 |2 |3 |4 
----------
sample 1|   sample 2    |sample 3   |sample 4   
----------
0,4704  |    0,1501     |0,4388    | 0,2957
```

What I want is to remove those numbers 1,2,3,4 and make sample 1, sample 2... as a header

here is also a link to the screenshot that I made [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G526C.png

What I tried so far is

```
df2=pd.read_csv('3.dat',sep='\t', header=None)
df2
df2=pd.read_csv('3.dat',sep='\t', header=None)
df2_transponed=df2.T
df2_transponed.to_csv('3_0T.dat', index=[1], header=None, sep='\t')
df2_transponed
```

Any suggestions would be helpful, thank you

Comment: `df2=pd.read_csv('3.dat', sep='\t', index_col=0, header=None).T`.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the column ´0´ as index first

```
df2.set_index(0).T
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done so far works. Just replace the header,

```
df.columns = df.iloc[1]
df = df.drop(df.index[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help. I finally was able to solve the problem

```
df2=pd.read_csv('Z.dat',sep='\t', header=None)
df2_transponed=df2.T
df2_transponed.to_csv('Z2.dat', header=True, sep='\t')
df2_transponed.columns = df2_transponed.iloc[0]
df3.to_csv('Z2.dat', header=True, sep='\t')
df3
```